# What does おせわになってます mean?

Tags: grammar, words, translation, meaning

> あなたにいつも**おせわになってます**からね.

What does the above sentence mean?

I'm confused about the `おせわになってます` part.

Comment: What don't you understand about it? Is it the vocabulary or the grammar or something else? Have you tried to find the answer anywhere else?

Comment: @ssb: It's the meaning that I don't understand. I think it means something in the line of "because i'm always taking care of you" but i'm not sure.

Comment: Since you have a specific question in your question body, a more descriptive title would be in order.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「あなたにいつもお世話になっていますからね」　means "It's because I'm always {indebting myself to you|being taken care of by you}, isn't it".

The "isn't it" part corresponds to ね, a detail we should not lose in the translation.

Why we might translate it as "indebting" or "always being" is because なっている/なっています is an -iru progressive verb: something going on rather than a finished action.

The に particle is tricky because of its multiple meanings. It can indicate an action toward something, but it also means "by" in passive senses, which is essentially the reverse. For instance "anata ni moratta X" means "the X given to me by you", which can also be expressed as "anata kara moratta X".

Comment: Note that the あなたに part makes this sentence very unnatural-sounding.

Comment: 「あなたには」のほうがいいですね。